# Deeply confused about $\sqrt[5]{a^5}=(a^5)^{1/5}$

Tags: fractions, radicals

So is this correct?

$\sqrt[5]{a^5} = \left(a^5\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$

I need proof why $\left(a^5\right)^\frac{1}{5}$ can or cannot just be $a^\frac{5}{5}$ or just $a$?

I think of that rule of

$\left(a^m\right)^n = a^{m·n}$ and clearly $a = \left(a^5\right)^\frac{1}{5}$ is false

What rule, or what evidence can I always prove to myself to never have this confusion again?

so why can you not just multiply  $\left(a^5\right)^\frac{1}{5}=a^\frac{5}{5}$? Cause fractions? Ok. I need confirmation.

If $\sqrt[5]{a^5} = \left(a^5\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$ is correct then is $\left(a^x\right)^\frac{m}{n} = \sqrt[n]{a^x}^m$ likewise?

I hate confusion and making the same math mistakes twice.

truly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could learn a little mathjax and write your question using it?

Comment: $\sqrt[\large 5]{a^5} = (a^5)^{1/5} = a \neq \dfrac{a^5}5$.

Comment: Try substituting a = -1

Comment: You should tell us more about the context. Because you tagged this with abstract algebra this is of paramount importance, because the answer depends heavily on the context. In general the rule
$$(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$$ only holds when $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers. This is in the context of rings. In a group they hold for all integers $m,n$. If $a$ can be any complex number, then the rule does not hold unless $m,n$ are integers. OTOH if all of $a,m,n$ are positive real numbers, then the powers can be defined in such a way that the rule holds. So. What is the context?

Comment: An algebra problem. Forgive my ignorance on mathjax.

Comment: "Clearly, $a=(a^5)^{\frac15}$ is false": What makes you say that ???

Comment: An algebra problem. Forgive my ignorance on mathjax. simplify 5th SQRT((96a^6/3a)) is clearly 5th SQRT(32a^5). My first thought is (32a^5)^1/5 = 5th SQRT(32a^5). Then I use the rule above, to get 32a^5/5 = 32a . Why is that usage wrong, and how can I clear future confusion, if the answer is 2a? I then solved it 5th SQRT(32*a^5) = 5th SQRT(32)*5th SQRT(a^5) = 2*a

Comment: I'm afraid calling it "an algebra problem" doesn't even begin to narrow the ambiguity down :-). Can you tell more about the level? If it is high school or precalculus algebra, then evinda's answer is probably a good fit. If $a$ can be negative, then the intricacies of complex powers enter the seen, and things break down in various degrees. If you get into abstract algebra (when $a$ is not necessarily a 'number'), then it may become meaningless.

Comment: Do not confuse $$a^{m/n}$$ and $$a^m/n$$

Comment: Indeed my tags were pitiful, yet I truly appreciate all your you're considerations. Seriously. Including anderstood's answer. Really. Thank you guys, have an awesome Friday.

Comment: From your late comments, it seems that the confusion is not on $\sqrt[5]{a^5}$ but on $\sqrt[5]{32a^5}$, which is $\sqrt[5]{32}\sqrt[5]{a^5}$. You should have asked the right question directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you are confused is because you think you are wrong about something, when you are actually right!

$(a^5)^{1/5}$ *is* just $a$.  In fact all of the expressions you list in your question are equal: $\sqrt[5]{a^5} = (a^5)^{1/5} = a^{5/5} = a^1 = a$.

You asked:  "Why can you not just multiply..."  and the answer is, you *can* just multiply.

**HOWEVER**:  All of this comes with one huge warning.  In general, this kind of manipulation only works if $a$ is *positive*.  If $a$ is *negative*, and if the the exponents involved are even, weird things can happen.

---

**EDIT**:  Now that I've seen your most recent comment, I think the issue has nothing to do with exponents or roots... It has to do with *parentheses*.  You asked:

> My first thought is (32a^5)^1/5 = 5th SQRT(32a^5). Then I use the rule above, to get 32a^5/5 = 32a . Why is that usage wrong, and how can I clear future confusion, if the answer is 2a?

The problem is that you forgot that the fifth root operation applies to *all* of $32a^5$.  So what you have is not $32a^{5/5} = 32a$, but rather $(32a^5)^{1/5}=2a$,  because the fifth root of $32$ is $2$.

Comment: This cleanly evens my confusion.

Answer (score 4):

It is known that for $n \geq 0,m>0, a\geq 0$:

$$\sqrt[m]{a^n}=(a^{n})^{\frac{1}{m}}=a^{\frac{n}{m}}$$

So:
$$\sqrt[5]{a^5}=a^{\frac{5}{5}}=a$$

Comment: I edited my answer!!!

Comment: Good (+1 and a smile)!

Answer (score 3):

Use the definition of $x^y$ for $x>0$, $x^y:=e^{y\ln x}$

For $a>0$,$$(a^5)^{\tfrac{1}{5}}=e^{\tfrac{1}{5}\ln(a^5)}=e^{\tfrac{5}{5}\ln(a)}=e^{\ln(a)}=a$$

For $a=0$, this definition can be continuously extended: $0^{\dfrac{1}{5}}=0$ (but not differentiable in $0$).

For $a<0$, a complex definition can be considered.

EDIT:

Not only is writing down the definition a good habit, it also makes it clear about where each variable live, which seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: I'm curious why I got downvotes...

Comment: It wasn't me, but I have heard that some users down vote, not because the answer is bad but just to keep an answer they find better higher up. They can make a difference of 2 with an up and a down. I don't do that though. I think that was a type of logic

Comment: So purely an ordering thing

Comment: @snulty: OK, never heard of this behaviour! At once I wondered if it was a bot because my score kept behaving like $1/2*((-1)^n-1)$ :D

Comment: btw, quite surprised nobody else mentioned $e^{y\ln x}$ which is always the first thing I consider when dealing with power functions!

Comment: Haha.  That's mad. Yeh especially when you're not just dealing with integers.

Answer (score 1):

Remember $$\sqrt[n]a: =a^{\frac1n},$$
$$(a^r)^s=a^{rs}.$$
where $n$ is an integer and $r, s$ are real. This is enough to handle all cases. (Actually, $n$ can be a real as well, but this is unusual with the root notation.)

So,
$$\sqrt[n]{a^m}=(a^m)^{\frac1n}=a^{m\cdot\frac1a}=a^{\frac mn}=a^{\frac1n\cdot m}=(\sqrt[n]a)^m.$$

When $n=m$, all these equal $a^1=a$.

UPDATE:
You also have
$$(ab)^r=a^rb^r,$$
which you can apply with the root notation:
$$\sqrt[n]{a^mb^m}=\sqrt[n]{(ab)^m}=(ab)^{\frac mn}=a^{\frac mn}b^{\frac mn}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}\sqrt[n]{b^m}=(\sqrt[n]a)^m(\sqrt[n]b)^m.$$