# Confusion about exponents like ${x^m}^{(1/n)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, roots, exponentiation

I've been reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884821/103816). It says that $\sqrt[m]{x^n} = x^{n\frac 1m}=x^{\frac mn}=x$ if $m=n$. Let's take $x=-2$, and $m=n=2$. Now we have,

$\sqrt[2]{(-2)^2}=\sqrt[2]{4}=2$

But according to that answer we must have $\sqrt[2]{(-2)^2}=(-2)^{2/2}=-2 $ So I guess that formula $\sqrt[n]{a^m}=(a^m)^{\frac1n}=a^{m\cdot\frac1a}=a^{\frac mn}=a^{\frac1n\cdot m}=(\sqrt[n]a)^m$ is not true for all real numbers. Also the [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884793/103816) suggest that the formula holds only when  $n≥0,m>0,x≥0$.

So the question is what is the correct formula which hold for negative values of $x$ too and where can I find a good explanation and proof of it. I've gone through the wikipedea artical http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation about it. It is very long and complex. I could not find a satisfactory explanation there.

Comment: In your first calculation, when you write that the square root of 4 is 2, you should really write that it's +/- 2, as -2 is also a square root of 4.

Comment: @logert According to the definition of principle nth-root, if the number is postitve then the principle nth root must also be positive.

Comment: The OTHER ANSWER that you've mentioned is correct !

Comment: Sure, we typically accept the positive root as the standard or "principle" one, but the negative works just as well. It's convention to only write the positive if that's all you're looking for, but mathematically the negative value is still a root. You should just think of square roots as asking "which numbers, when squared, give me this number"? And the answer to that question is both 2 and -2 in the case of the square root of 4.

Comment: @logert No, $\sqrt 4 =+2$. my keyboard is not workin ill reply-later

Comment: If you want $x^{n/m}$ = $x$ , then n$\ge$0 , m$\gt$0 , and x$\ge$0.

Comment: @VikrantDesai $x\geq 0$ is sufficient

Comment: @MattSamuel you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in noticing that the principle value of $\sqrt[n]{x^n} \neq x$ when $x$ is negative and $n$ is even. In this instance, though, you can say that $\sqrt[n]{(x)^n} = |x|$

Comment: Is x being negative and n being even the only exception? Could you tell me some reference or book which explains it adequately and considers all possible cases.

Comment: @user103816: To cover all possible cases, you have no choice but to deal with the complex exponential function, its multi-valued inverse called the complex logarithm and its branch cuts.